# Implementing Null Object Design Pattern in Spring beans

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, null, spring-3

I am using a CustomerDTO:

```
public class CustomerDTO {

    private int customerId;
    private String customerName;
    private String customerAddress;
    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }
    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }
    public String getCustomerAddress() {
        return customerAddress;
    }
    public void setCustomerAddress(String customerAddress) {
        this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
    }

}
```

Then I am using CustomerDAO where I am fetching customer based on the customerId

```
public class CustomerDAO {
    private CustomerDTO customer;

    public void setCustomer(CustomerDTO customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public CustomerDTO getCustomer(int customerId){
        try{
            if("you get customer based on customer id") then "return the customer";
        }catch(Exception ex){
            return new CustomerDTO();
              //some other work
        }
    }
}
```

Now this code `new CustomerDTO();` in CustomerDAO is giving `null` when I am trying to access `new CustomerDTO().getCustomerName()`. I am thinking about initializing the field with default values.

How can I achieve this with/without Spring framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with Spring

```
@Value("myValue")
String customerName;
```

And without spring, just assign value in declaration itself,

```
 private String customerName="myValue";
```

Comment: Yeah, just initialize the field in the declaration itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it is giving null. I have already tried it with spring.xml and now with annotation. I think possible problem is that when I am doing `new CustomerDTO()` then the bean is not initialized by spring container. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @ritesh yes,  `new CustomerDTO()` is just create a bean instance directly not using spring. but if you assign `default value`, it will never return null. here you are not using spring. in spring you have to create instance through `_springContext.getBean(beanName)`

Comment: I was not creating bean through springContext...This was my mistake. Thanks for answer :)